# Finding the biggest subset of elements that does not correlate

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of integers and I want to find the largest subset in which the elements does not correlate with each other in a specific way. For example a subset in which if any of the elements is multiplied by 13 the result is not in the subset.

My first thought is to iterate through all the possible subsets, filter out these that don't meet the condition and then find the largest one, but this is too slow and I don't know how to generate all possible subsets.

Comment: The answer is going to depend heavily on what you mean "correlate". An obvious example is the relation of `sum{subset} = sum{set}/2`, which is the partition problem, and there is no known efficient (polynomial time) for it. (In case of integers there is pseudo-polynomial one)

Comment: However, if the question is only "How to create all possible subsets" - this is going to be a dupe, there are plenty of questions about it here. (simple explanation, use recursion, and for each element "guess" if it in the subset or not and recurse, when coming back from recursion, "guess" the other option.

Comment: The question is how to find the number of elements in the largest subset.

Comment: Then it depends on the exact relationship.

Comment: Relationship is the following : if you multiple any of the elements in the subset by some number the resulting number does not have to be in the subset.

Comment: A friend just gave me the following idea : multiply all the elements in the original set by number ( for example 13 ) and record the result in multipliedSet. Then remove all elements in the original set that overlap with the elements in multipliedSet. The idea sounds good, but I'm sure if this will work in all scenarios.

Comment: Doesn't sound optimal to me, since you remove ALL elements that overlap in the big subset, while you may keep some of them, that happen to be not included in the subset. Example: C=13, `arr=[1,2,13,26, 169]` - optimal solution would be `[1,26,169]` - but you will exclude some of its elements

Comment: If we remove all the overlapping elements we will be left with `[1, 2, 26]` which is also correct, since we are not interested in which exactly are the elements, rather than their count.

Comment: 1,2,26 is incorrect, because 2*13=26. Removing all overlapping will remove 26 as well, and you will get [1,2] only - which is suboptimal.

Comment: I'll be happy any ideas that you have :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll be answering this one (from comments). In general there's no good solution for any "correlation"

> Relationship is the following : if you multiple any of the elements in the subset by some number the resulting number does not have to be in the subset.

If your number is `m`

You can generate all chains `x`, `x*m`, `x*m*m`, ...., such that all number in chain are in the set, `x/m` is not

Remove every second element, i.e `x*m^2`, `x*m^4` from original set. Elements left are your target set.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to build a graph and find the vertexes with most edges and remove them until you get rid of all edges. Complexity is about O(N^2).

Here is a detailed algorithm:

```
for each possible pair (x, y) from the source set
begin
    if x = y * 13 or y = x * 13 then make edge between x and y
end
while graph has edges
begin
    let V = find: a vertex with maximum count of edges (it can be 1 or 2)
    remove V from the graph
end
result: the remaining vertexes in the graph
```